# Simple Q: From Timestamp args to Date

Tags: angular, date, time, timestamp, frontend

I have the arguments -- seconds and nanoseconds -- of a Timestamp, but in the frontend, I'd like to get a Date with those arguments.

How can I do this?

Example:

I have:

```
_nanoseconds: 0
_seconds: 1586833200
```

I want to get a a Date with that.

Comment: When you say `_seconds` what is it? How are you checking this seconds and from what time?

Answer (score 0):

second

```
<h1>{{new Date(1586833200*1000)|date:'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss'}}</h1>
```

microsecond

```
<h1>{{new Date(1586833200000)|date:'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss'}}</h1>
```